# Not able to grant USAGE, SELECT permission to all sequences using node pg package

Tags: postgresql, pg

I am writing a script which creates a new user and give SELECT permission to all the sequences. The query I am running is `GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO username`. After running the script when I try to to SELECT the sequence, it shows permission denied but when I run script again and try to select again, it works. Can someone help me here?

Comment: "permission denied for GRANT" or "permission denied to use sequence"?

Comment: @Bergi Permission denied to use sequence